# Get post_author email for Zapier Integration

Tags: functions, hooks, author

I'm creating an automation on zapier that allows you to send a notification to the authors of the posts based on the status of the post.

Among the various post fields there is no "user_email" which is essential for sending the email in the field, To:

Is there any way to record this field so that it later emerges in the post fields?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way of getting the post author's email from a post. You can get the email by using the author ID, which is present in standard WP_Post object.

```
$post_author_id = intval( $post->post_author );
$post_author_email = get_the_author_meta('email', $post_author_id);
```

Or if you just have the post ID

```
$post_author_id = intval( get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ) );
$post_author_email = get_the_author_meta('email', $post_author_id);
```

Or if you want, you could also hook custom function to `save_post` action and save the author email to the post's meta, when the post is created. Then you could get the email with `get_post_meta()` using post ID and the custom key you used to save the meta.